# nested lists - typeset only top n levels

Tags: lists, enumitem, nesting

I am writing an outline and have a lot of nested `enumitem` lists.  Is there a way to automatically suppress output for higher list levels? e.g. In the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
```

How do I print a concise version of my outline by printing only the first-level `\items` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More general method doing all of `enumerate`, `itemize`, and `description` and allowing to specify  a level `N`.

[there was temporarily a problem which impacted vertical spacing, this is now fixed. Final version.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
% GENERAL PURPOSE ENVIRONMENT SWALLOWING
% #1 is the name of the surrounding environment
% we swallow everything until finding the correct \end
% then we reinject \end{#1}
\def\@scoop{\@scoop}

\long\def\scoop  #1#2\end #3{\def\scoop@env{#1}\scoop@i #2\begin\@scoop }

\long\def\scoop@i #1\begin #2{\def\scoop@tmp{#2}%
                        \ifx\scoop@tmp\@scoop
                             \expandafter\scoop@end
                        \else\expandafter\scoop@ii
                        \fi }

\long\def\scoop@ii #1\begin\@scoop #2\end #3{\scoop@i #2\begin\@scoop }

\def\scoop@end {\expandafter\end\expandafter{\scoop@env}}

\makeatother

%% PATCHING THE enumerate, itemize and description ENVIRONMENTS
%%   *** FROM ENUMITEM ***
%% (starred environments enumerate*, etc.. NOT DONE)

\makeatletter
\def\end@concise {\def\endenumerate   {\enit@endenumerate}%
                  \def\enditemize     {\enit@enditemize}%
                  \def\enddescription {\enit@enddescription}}


\newcount\cnt@concise
\cnt@concise\@M

% à cause des \relax dans \renewenvironment? non.
% \def\@MAKECONCISE {%
%        \renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]
%           {\scoop {enumerate}}{\aftergroup\end@concise\ignorespacesafterend}%
%        \renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]
%           {\scoop {itemize}}{\aftergroup\end@concise\ignorespacesafterend}%
%        \renewenvironment{description}[1][]
%           {\scoop {description}}{\aftergroup\end@concise\ignorespacesafterend}%
% }%

% OK I have solved it. Must be something done by enumitem.sty which didn't
% like the modification to \endenumerate etc..., so we delay. It works.
\def\@MAKECONCISE@i {%
    \def\enumerate   {\@MAKECONCISE@ii \scoop {enumerate}}%
    \def\itemize     {\@MAKECONCISE@ii \scoop {itemize}}%
    \def\description {\@MAKECONCISE@ii \scoop {description}}%
}%

\def\@MAKECONCISE@ii {%
    \def\endenumerate {\aftergroup\end@concise\ignorespacesafterend}%
    \let\enditemize     \endenumerate
    \let\enddescription \endenumerate
}% 

\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]
  {\advance\cnt@concise-\@ne\ifnum\cnt@concise<\@ne\@MAKECONCISE@i\fi
   \enit@enumerate\enitdp@enumerate{enum}\thr@@{#1}}
  {\enit@endenumerate}

\renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]
  {\advance\cnt@concise-\@ne\ifnum\cnt@concise<\@ne\@MAKECONCISE@i\fi
   \enit@itemize\enitdp@itemize{item}\thr@@{#1}}
  {\enit@enditemize}

\renewenvironment{description}[1][]
  {\advance\cnt@concise-\@ne\ifnum\cnt@concise<\@ne\@MAKECONCISE@i\fi
   \enit@description\enitdp@description{description}\@M{#1}}
  {\enit@enddescription}

\newcommand{\SetConciseLevelTo}[1]{\cnt@concise #1\relax }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hrule
\medskip

\texttt{CONCISE LEVEL = 1}
\SetConciseLevelTo {1}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{description}
  \item[More elaboration of the First point:] here we explain more things.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item specific details ...
    \item ... and again specific details
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
   \end{itemize}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

Again:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{description}
  \item[More elaboration of the First point:] here we explain more things.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item specific details ...
    \item ... and again specific details
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
   \end{itemize}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\hrule
\medskip
\texttt{CONCISE LEVEL = 2}

\SetConciseLevelTo {2}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{description}
  \item[More elaboration of the First point:] here we explain more things.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item specific details ...
    \item ... and again specific details
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details]...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\hrule
\medskip
\texttt{CONCISE LEVEL = 3}

\SetConciseLevelTo {3}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{description}
  \item[More elaboration of the First point:] here we explain more things.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item specific details ...
    \item ... and again specific details
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
   \end{itemize}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\hrule
\medskip
\texttt{CONCISE LEVEL = 1}

\SetConciseLevelTo {1}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{description}
  \item[More elaboration of the First point:] here we explain more things.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item specific details ...
    \item ... and again specific details
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details] ...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{description}
    \item[Specific details]...
    \end{description}
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: concise lists]

---

**first version**

(I think there was a bug, but it doesn't matter now)

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
% GENERAL PURPOSE ENVIRONMENT SWALLOWING
% #1 is the name of the surrounding environment
% we swallow everything until finding the correct \end
% then we reinject \end{#1}
\def\@scoop{\@scoop}

\long\def\scoop  #1#2\end #3%
    {\def\scoop@env{#1}\scoop@i #2\@scoop\begin\@scoop }

\long\def\scoop@i #1\begin #2{\def\scoop@tmp{#2}%
                        \ifx\scoop@tmp\@scoop
                             \expandafter\scoop@end
                        \else\expandafter\scoop@ii
                        \fi }

\long\def\scoop@ii #1\@scoop\begin\@scoop #2\end #3%
     {\scoop@i #2\@scoop\begin\@scoop }

\def\scoop@end {\expandafter\end\expandafter{\scoop@env}}

% 
\def\endscoop {\def\endenumerate{\enit@endenumerate}}
%

\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]
  {\ifConcise
       \renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]{\scoop {enumerate}}{\endscoop \par}%
   \fi
   \enit@enumerate\enitdp@enumerate{enum}\thr@@{#1}}
  {\enit@endenumerate}
\makeatother

\newif\ifConcise


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\hrule
\smallskip

\texttt{CONCISE IS TRUE}
\Concisetrue
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
\texttt{CONCISE IS NOW FALSE}

\Concisefalse
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
\texttt{CONCISE IS AGAIN TRUE}

\Concisetrue
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item First point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Second point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Third point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Third point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth point concisely.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
  \item Fourth point in elaboration.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Specific details...
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\smallskip
\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: concise enumerates]

Comment: That seems to work-- I need to pull out a TeXbook to decipher it. Is the use of "enumerate" hardcoded into \def\endscoop ? it might be nice to work for itemize environments too, above a certain level.  hoping for something more general.. ideally with an argument [n] to automatically suppress if level > n. But I will play with this and see what I can make it do.

Comment: Works like a charm!  incidentally, the example is more readable if you put the content of the outline in a \def.